# How can I privent the list used as a map value from being modified?

Tags: java, list, dictionary

```
Map<String, list> map = new HashMap();
List list = new ArrayList();

list.add("1");
list.add("2");
list.add("3");

map.put("first", list);
list.clear();

System.out.println(map.get("first"));  // = null
```

I want to use it for various maps by using a list in the value part of the map.

It can't be used because it keeps being modified. Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `new ArrayList<>` created out of the list instead of adding the reference to the map. When you add the reference, any change in the object through the reference will be reflected everywhere this object has been referenced (by this reference).

Do it as follows:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        list.add("1");
        list.add("2");
        list.add("3");

        map.put("first", new ArrayList<String>(list));
        list.clear();

        System.out.println(map.get("first"));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

On a side note, do not use a [raw type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) e.g. you should use `List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();` instead of `List list = new ArrayList();`.

Comment: Thank you! Thanks to that, I realized the concept and solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a reference in Java this is done by copying the reference. You will therefore end up with two references to the same list instance. The first one being `list`, the second one being the one you placed in your map. Edits via either one of these references will modify the same instance.
If you want distinct instances, you have to copy your list. 
This can be done with the [Collections.copy()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/collections-copy-method-in-java-with-examples/) method or as Arvind Kumar Avinash already pointed out, through the use of the copy constructor.